# Converting an ArrayList<int[]> to an int[][]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a really simple question, but I just want to know what the correct way of doing it is.

How do you convert a variable of type `ArrayList<int[]>` to an `int[][]`?

Comment: I don't think that ArrayList<int[]> would ever exist.

Comment: An `ArrayList<int[]>` would never compile, but you might get one in some roundabout way since an `int[]` is an `Object` after all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`List#toArray(T[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) wherein you pass the array type.

```
int[][] intMatrix = listOfIntArrays.toArray(new int[0][]);
```

Demo:

```
List<int[]> listOfIntArrays = new ArrayList<int[]>();
listOfIntArrays.add(new int[] { 10, 20, 30 });
listOfIntArrays.add(new int[] { 11, 21, 31 });
listOfIntArrays.add(new int[] { 12, 22, 32 });

int[][] intMatrix = listOfIntArrays.toArray(new int[0][]);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(intMatrix));
```

Result:

```
[[10, 20, 30], [11, 21, 31], [12, 22, 32]]
```

Comment: Is it really needed to pass the size of the List to the `int[][]` array constructor? Isn't `toArray(new int[0][]);` enough?

Comment: Yeah, `toArray` just needs some non-null array object of the type you're expecting to resolve the type. Matching the size is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, I only knew about the simple `.toArray()` method before, without any arguments.

Comment: @Martijn: I never realized that, but you're entirely right. Thanks and I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Martijn: I rarely used this construct in practice (even more, I think *never*) and I just learnt about it based on answers here and there at forums. The majority of them pass the original list's size along.

Answer (score 1):

let `a = ArrayList<int[]>`
then to convert it to an `int[][]` you say, for example, `int[][] b = a.toArray(new int[a.size()][])`